# how to downcase rootviewcontroller from appdelegate to define NSPersistentContainer in Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I'm trying to follow the steps [Setting Up a Core Data Stack documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/setting_up_a_core_data_stack?language=objc) for setting up Core Data using Objective-C but it appears to only show Swift implementation. The main view controller I have is of class `TodoListTableViewController`, which is embedded in a navigation controller like so:

> Application Entry Point->`UINavigationController`->`TodoListTableViewController`

I tried defining my `-[UIApplicationDelegate application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:]` like so:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    if (self.persistentContainer == nil) {
        [NSException raise:@"did not initialize persistent container in app delegate" format:@"no init"];
    }

    UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
    TodoListTableViewController *todoListVC = [mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"TodoListTableViewController"];
    todoListVC.persistentContainer = self.persistentContainer;
    UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:todoListVC];
    self.window.rootViewController = navController;
    
    return YES;
}
```

but I'm getting a missing container exception since I added a check for the existence of `persistentContainer` in `TodoListTableViewController` class like so:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
   [super viewDidLoad];
   if (self.persistentContainer == nil) {
     [NSException raise:@"missing container" format:@"missing container"];
   }
}
```

---

**EDIT**: below is the boilerplate Ccore Data related code in my `AppDelegate` class for adding both the persistent container and context generated by Xcode when opting in for Core Data, that I'm using:

```
@synthesize persistentContainer = _persistentContainer;

- (NSPersistentContainer *)persistentContainer {
    // The persistent container for the application. This implementation creates and returns a container, having loaded the store for the application to it.
    @synchronized (self) {
        if (_persistentContainer == nil) {
            _persistentContainer = [[NSPersistentContainer alloc] initWithName:@"ToDoList"];
            [_persistentContainer loadPersistentStoresWithCompletionHandler:^(NSPersistentStoreDescription *storeDescription, NSError *error) {
                if (error != nil) {
                    // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
                    // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
                    
                    /*
                     Typical reasons for an error here include:
                     * The parent directory does not exist, cannot be created, or disallows writing.
                     * The persistent store is not accessible, due to permissions or data protection when the device is locked.
                     * The device is out of space.
                     * The store could not be migrated to the current model version.
                     Check the error message to determine what the actual problem was.
                    */
                    NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, error.userInfo);
                    abort();
                }
            }];
        }
    }
    
    return _persistentContainer;
}

#pragma mark - Core Data Saving support

- (void)saveContext {
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = self.persistentContainer.viewContext;
    NSError *error = nil;
    if ([context hasChanges] && ![context save:&error]) {
        // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
        // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, error.userInfo);
        abort();
    }
}
```

And the header file included by xcode in AppDelegate:

```
@property (readonly, strong) NSPersistentContainer *persistentContainer;
```

thank you.

Comment: Have you checked whether your app delegate's `persistentContainer` is non-nil at the time you call the line `todoListVC.persistentContainer = self.persistentContainer;`? Have you verified that that line is being called before `viewDidLoad`?

Comment: How is your `persistentContainer` property  defined in the application delegate class?

Comment: @HangarRash thanks. I didn't, even after adding the check, I'm getting the same error. I'll update the code to include the nil check

Comment: @TheDreamsWind I'll update the code for the persistentContainer property since the implementation is long

Comment: @reactor i can't spot anything that can cause the exception thrown the code you provided. Especially since you have `self.persistentContainer == nil` check in the `AppDelegate` class. You either should have the `AppDelegate` class released for whatever reason (provided you controller doesn't retain the pointer to the persistent container) OR which is more likely - you have another instance of `TodoListTableViewController` allocated somewhere, which doesn't have `persistentContainer` set up. E.g. the storyboard may instantiate a `TodoListTableViewController` as part of the designed hierarchy

Comment: @TheDreamsWind chatgpt had advised that the above is the way I should use the view controller added with storyboard. apparently, there's another version of instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier which includes a `creator` argument, which is a block with access to an `NSCoder`. however, that doesn't work either

Comment: @reactor with help of debugger you can just check whether the controller instance where the exception gets thrown and the controller you create in the `-[UIApplicationDelegate application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:]` have the same addresses. If the addresses are the same, keep digging into the property of the controller (when it changes and to what values), if addresses are different, find out where the redundant controller come from.

Comment: @TheDreamsWind yes! I'm seeing that the addresses are different. I even tried to override `initWithCoder` and am seeing this being called twice for the same view controller. How would I make sure that it's only called once for the view controller I added using storyboard?

Comment: I found a solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41243007/how-to-include-nspersistentcontainer-in-appdelegate where instead of passing the persistent container from the appdelegate, I would define it in the view controller like so `self.persistentContainer = ((AppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate).persistentContainer;`. I'm not super happy about this solution but it's the only one I found that works. if there's a better solution, I'm game.